# React Query, repeated mutation at a certain error status code

Tags: reactjs, react-query

Example:

The server returns two error codes, if 503 requests are returned we need to repeat the request, if 400 then show the user the error.

When implementing without a react query through a normal repeated request with an interval, everything works fine. That is, if error 503 is returned, the interval is started and a repeat request is made every 10 seconds, as soon as error 503 disappears, the interval is reset and the request disappears.

How to achieve the same behavior with react query?

```
export const useCreatePost = () => {

  const { isLoading, isSuccess, isError} = useMutation(
    ['createPost'],
    () => createPost(),
    {
      onError: (err: any) => {
        if (err?.status === 503 || err?.status === 0) {
          ???
        } else {
          console.error('createPost error', err?.status)
        }
      },
    })

  return { isLoading, isSuccess, isError}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

React-query natively supports retrying mutations:

> By default React Query will not retry a mutation on error, but it is possible with the retry option:

```js
const mutation = useMutation(addTodo, {
  retry: 3,
})
```

> If mutations fail because the device is offline, they will be retried in the same order when the device reconnects.

[Documentation](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/mutations#retry)

If you want a 10 second delay, add a `retryDelay: 10_000` property.

Comment: Yes, but I need to respond to a specific error code, for example if the error code is 400, then just throw the error, if the status is different, then make a repeat request

Comment: @happy_cutman you should be able to just throw the error you got in onError()

Comment: retry can be a function that receives the error. in there, you can return true or false if you want to retry or not, depending on the error status code. It will retry as long as true is returned from that function. @SlavaKnyazev do you want to amend your answer? Otherwise, I would create a separate one ...

Comment: @TkDodo could you show me what the code looks like in my case? Please ) Some example

Comment: @TkDodo like this?

`retry: error => error?.status === 503 && true`

Comment: retry: error => errors.status === 503